# Adding Java jar as Ubuntu service

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am trying to add my java jar application to Ubuntu as service so that when the Ubuntu server is restarted I dont need to manually run the jar command to run my application. At present I have to run this cmd on the terminal 
*java -jar myapp.jar -conf conf.json.*

I came accross this link which would have solved my problem but for some reason the service is not running when i run the service as described in that website.

http://www.jcgonzalez.com/ubuntu-16-java-service-wrapper-example

Can someone please help me!!

Comment: How to I add -conf config.json to this line `nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &`

Answer (score 0):

I think your bash script should have "nohup" like this:

```
nohup java -jar myapp.jar -conf conf.json  &
```

Comment: like so
nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR -conf config.json &>> MyService.out 2>&1&

Comment: I think the last ampersand have a gap is better for reading:
nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR -conf config.json >> MyService.out 2>&1  &

Comment: I get this error when I try to start the service
`/usr/local/bin/TutisService.sh: 9: /usr/local/bin/TutisService.sh: cannot create TutisService.out: Permission denied`

Comment: @ZAJ make sure you have set all the necessary permissions. But better still run your script at your designated DIRs or $HOME.

Comment: OK, I gave this path the permission /usr/local/bin and now i can start the service in the sense it says service started but when i tryo stop the service it gives me this message`tutis@tutis:/usr/local/bin$ TutisService.sh stop
TutisService stoping ...
/usr/local/bin/TutisService.sh: 20: kill: No such process

TutisService stopped ...`